# Is the following matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Determine if this matrix is diagonalizable.
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\sqrt2}2 & 0 & -\frac{\sqrt2}2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{\sqrt2}2 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt2}2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I worked out the determinant of its characteristic equation and got 1 real eigenvalue and 2 other imaginary eigenvalues. I concluded to say that the matrix was NOT diagonalizable because by definition $\dim(C)$ needs to equal # of distinct eigenvalues for the matrix to be diagonalizable. in this case there is only one real distinct eigenvalues and $\dim(C)=3$. Are imaginary eigenvalues distinct? I don't think so. What do you think?

Comment: It's almost impossible to understand what you wrote for $\;C\;$ . Please do follow the easy directions of the site to write mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

This matrix represents a rotation around the axis $y$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions)). So it is not diagonalizable in $M(3;\mathbb{R})$.  The only real eigenspace is spanned by the eigenvector $(0,1,0)^T$ of the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$. The other two eigenvalues are $\lambda_{2,3}=\frac{1\pm i} {\sqrt{2}}$ and have no real eigenvectors.

Comment: A rotation matrix is not diagonalizable over the field of all reals but is diagonalizable over the field of all complex, how did you determine that M(3;all real)?

Comment: I've said that the matrix **is not diagonalizable in $M(3,\mathbb{R})$**, but obviously it is diagonalizable in $M(3,\mathbb{C})$ since it has three different eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C}$, so we have three linearly independent eigenspaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you have eigenvalues real $\lambda$ and complex $\gamma$, you will have  $\overline{\gamma}$ since if a complex number is a root of a polynomial (characteristic equation), so is its conjugate. These are three distinct eigenvalues.

In short, an imaginary eigenvalue still counts.

Note: I did not check your computation because it is hard to read your post with the current formatting.